# Run method when Change Tab Controller tab (iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have xamarin ios app, with Tab Bar.

When I run main tab, I call methods

Here is code of main tab

```
public partial class ExperienceTableViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ExperienceTableViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }
    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        List<GettingExperiences.Experience> tableItems =  new List<GettingExperiences.Experience>();
        tableItems.Clear();
        tableItems = await ExperienceMethods.GetExperiencesAsync();
        ExperienceTableView.Source = new ExperienceSource(tableItems, this, this.NavigationController);
        ExperienceTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        ExperienceTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 80f;
        ExperienceTableView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

When I change filters in another tab, I need to get back and rerun  this method - `tableItems = await ExperienceMethods.GetExperiencesAsync();`

I make redirect like this

`this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;` from another tab, but my method not reruns.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem

just run method in `ViewDidAppear()` or using events

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidLoad is only run once, First time view is loaded. After next time ViewWillAppear(), ViewDidAppear() will be executed. As View is already there in tab bar controller.

So If your ViewController is part of Tab bar you should put your always executing code in ViewWillAppear() and ViewDidAppear(). And code which only is needed to be run once should e placed in ViewDidLoad().